# Prove integral is greater than $0$

Tags: analysis, integration

$f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $I=[a,b]$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in I$, prove $\int_a^b f(x) dx >0$ .

Need help on this question, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I hope that you know that (with obvious meaning of notation) (all depending on your definition of the integral)
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\; dx \geq \sum_{i}[\inf_{[x_i, x_{i+1}]} f(x)]\Delta x
$$
for all partitions of $[a,b]$, where $\inf$ is the infimum of $f$ over each subinterval.

Now the claim is that there is a $\delta >0$ and a subinterval $[x_1 , x_{i+1}]$ such that $f(x) \geq \delta$ on that interval. Suppose this wasn't true. Then
$$
\sum_{i}[\inf_{[x_i, x_{i+1}]} f(x)]\Delta x = 0
$$
for all pertitions. And so (taking the limit) the integral would be $0$.

So there is an interval $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$ and a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x)\geq \delta$ for all $x\in [x_i, x_{i+1}]$.

So now you have that $f(x)\geq \delta >0$ on an interval $[x_i , x_{i+1}]$. So then
$$
\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f(x)\; dx \geq \delta(x_{i+1} - x_i) > 0.
$$
So
$$
\int_{a}^b f(x)\; dx = \int_a^{x_i} f(x)\; dx + \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f(x)\; dx + \int_{x_{i+1}}^b f(x)\; dx > 0.
$$
(Assuming that you are fine with saying that the first and last integral definitely are greater then or equal to $0$).

Comment: `This answer proves that if the integral of f on I is positive then there exists a nondegenerate interval J and some positive δ such that f⩾δ on J, and that if there exists a nondegenerate interval J and some positive δ such that f⩾δ on J then the integral of f on I is positive`. These implications are true but they do not solve the question. Better?

Answer (score 4):

The integral is at least as big as any lower sum that you compute. Show that every lower sum is greater than zero.

Comment: but we need inf f(x) to compute lower sum.Since inf f(x) could be 0, so could lower sum.

Comment: "Show that every lower sum is greater than zero." Not true.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, then there is a point $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f$ is continuous at $c$ (in fact, $f$ is continuous almost everywhere in $[a,b]\,$). Since $f(c)>0$, it follows that there is a non-degenerate interval $I\subset[a,b]$ and a positive number $\alpha$ such that $f(x)\ge \alpha$ for all $x\in I$.  We then have, by the nonnegativity of $f$, that $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\ge \int_{I} f(x)\,dx>0$.